# Android Studio 2.1.1 : Webview Display Nothing

Tags: android, webview

please help me

I have a problem with my webview 
its working lately and then a few days its not working i dont know what happen 
i run it again 
only display a white/blank page

here is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("www.google.com");
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }




}


public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
        //To Prevent  Web page not available
        if (errorCode == -2) {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#7F02AE'><b>Your Project</b></font>"));
            builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#120049'>Your data services are not working.Please check your data services.</font>"));
            builder.setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#7F02AE'><b>OK</b></font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // In Case of Fragment instead of Activity Replace getApplicationContext()  with getActivity()
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
            dialog.dismiss();


        }
    });
            builder.setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#7F02AE'><b>Retry</b></font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
                    startActivity(intent);


                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();


        }

    }
}
```

and  here is my AndroidManifest.xml

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

i tried to look for basic tutorials about webview again maybe i missing something but when i try 
they all just a blank page 
nothing display maybe my 
android studio got a problem

Comment: add requestPermission for runtime permission and paste http://www.google.com

Comment: sorry but can you be more precise 
thank you :)